# php: cannot get the value of $state in ajax.php file. even not working with isset(). please let me know what is the solution

Tags: php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'slcsa');
?>

<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Select State</td>
        <td>
            <select id="statedd" onchange="change_state()"> 
            <!--we will add onchange to perform Ajax using function change_state()-->
                <option value="">Select</option>
<?php 
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM state_code");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row["State Code"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["State Name"]; ?> </option>
<?php
    }
?>
            </select><
        /td>
    </tr>
    <!--create another dropdownlist-->
    <tr>
        <td>Select District</td>
        <td>
            <div id="districtdd">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>       
    </table>    
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_state()
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax.php?state="+document.getElementById("statedd").value, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
    document.getElementById("districtdd").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
</script>


this is ajax.php

<?php
//$state=intval($_POST['state']);
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'slcsa');
if (!$link) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connection to database established";

//$state = (isset($_POST['state']) ? $_POST['state'] : null);

//if(isset($_POST["state"])){
    //$state=$_POST["state"];
//}

$state=$_POST['state']; //my query is not working. I am not able to get $sate value. here $sate value cannot get the value.

if ($state!=""){
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM district_code WHERE State Code='".$state."'");
    echo "<select>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        echo "<option>"; echo $row["District Name"]; echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

use empty() to check value of state is empty or not use $_REQUEST[state] to get the value from url

```
  $state=$_POST['state']  ;
  if (!empty($state)){
                $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM district_code WHERE State Code='".$state."'");
                echo "<select>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<option>".$row["District Name"]."</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
            }
```

To POST data like an HTML form, add an HTTP header with setRequestHeader(). Specify the data you want to send in the send() method:**since you are using POST you must send value as argument in `send()`**

```
function change_state(st)
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");// without this line output will not change
    xmlhttp.send("state="+st); 
    document.getElementById("districtdd").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}

<select onchange=change_state(this.value)>’
```

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest (async = false) is not recommended because
>   the JavaScript will stop executing until the server response is ready.
>   If the server is busy or slow, the application will hang or stop.
>
> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest is in the process of being removed from the
>   web standard, but this process can take many years.
>
> Modern developer tools are encouraged to warn about using synchronous
>   requests and may throw an InvalidAccessError exception when it occurs.

[check out this example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2)

Comment: Thanks Jasinth for reply. Even after using above code the district name is not populating. Still query is unable to process. I think $state is not able to receive the value from index.php file...Also plz let me know if there is any error with this line " xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax.php?state="+document.getElementById("statedd").value, false);"...

Comment: Also array key is missing in ajax.php file

Comment: @ShahnawazKhan the mistake is you didn't specify the index value in `send()`  now i have update with necessary  information

Comment: are you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: @Jasinth...I am satisfied with your answer. the above code is working with $_GET. Even after editing the above code still, it's not working...I have seen the suggestion in w3school but still i my code is not running with $_POST. Thanks for giving you time...If you find the solution plz let me know

Comment: @ShahnawazKhan did you pass values like this `xmlhttp.send("state="+st);`

Comment: use onreadystatechange e.g `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };`

Comment: I have even tried this method too but not working. Ajax request is being send but the ajax.php file is not able to retrieve value. this code is working with$ajax({method,url,data,submission function(data){(#filename).html(data)} but not working with xmlhttr.open() & send method